# How to disable a widget when dependent plugin is inactive?

Tags: plugins, widgets

My widget has a lot of dependent plugins, and disabling one of the plugins results in erratic behavior throughout my entire WP installation.

I've been trying to use the function is_plugin_active('Widget_Class_Name') with little to no luck thus far. Is there an effective way to remove the widget altogether if one of its dependent plugins are inactive?

Answer (score 3):

well first of all, [`is_plugin_active`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) takes the name of the plugin sub-directory/file, so passing it a classname won't work. I'm not sure why you're passing anything widget related if you're checking for plugins your widget depends on.

other options are php's `class_exists` and `function_exists` to check if plugin functions your widget uses exist. check in the widgets init hook and don't register your widget if a class or function it depends on doesn't exist.

Comment: I actually meant to talk about unregister_widget("Widget_Class_Name") - sorry about that.